# Ruby On Rails Scaffold LoadError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scaffolding, scriptgenerate

I am learning Ruby on Rails using a book I picked up called "Head First Rails"  I am in the first chapter and it tells me to create my `CRUD` procedures using the following command:

```
ruby script/generate scaffold ticket name:string seat_id_seq:string address:text price_paid:decimal email_address:string
```

the error I am getting is:

`ruby: No such file or directory -- script/generate (LoadError)`

Can someone please explain what I am doing wrong.  I am not new to development, I am a professional C# developer trying to learn Ruby on Rails.

Comment: i got the same problem, but generate what is? cause inside of the rails app there is no a directory called generate inside of  script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you running that in your application directory? The scaffold command needs to be executed in your application directory in order to find script/generate.

Comment: ah, this was it, i was in the parent directory of my project and not in my project directory, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

try simply "./script/generate ..." in your project directory

Answer (score 0):

This question is old, but for anyone who is having problems with "Head First Rails" first edition (which is the only one available at this time), it was written for rails 2. So most of the commands, like script/generate, have been replaced by new ones in Rails 3.

I suggest using "Agile Web Development with Rails" book.